# Submit a Post to symfony FosRestBundle

Tags: rest, symfony, post, response, fosrestbundle

As I try to use a REST API, I setted up a simple controller which should only return my POST Vars as a xml response.

Unfortunately, it won't return it. I guess I have some probs by getting the data from the request.

This is my Action inside the Controller. GET works fine, but POST won't do.

```
 public function postAuthAction (Request $request)
 { 
   #$request      = $this->get('request'); 
   $username = $request->request->get('Username'); 
   $password = $request->request->get('Password'); 
   $data=array("user"=>$username,"password"=>$password);
   return $data;
 }
```

It only returns me:

```
 <result>
   <entry>
     <entry xsi:nil="true"/>
     <entry xsi:nil="true"/>
   </entry>
 </result>
```

Which isn't that bad for the reason that it returns anything at all ;)

I extpected something like

```
 <result>
    <user>POST Username</user>
    <password>POST Password</password>
 </result>
```

What am I doing wrong? IO don't get it.

EDIT: my POST

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <Login>
       <Username>abc</Username>
       <Password>pass12</Password>
 </Login>
```

Comment: How do you test postAuthAction?

Comment: I'm using the firefox RestClient https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/restclient/ see my edited question

Comment: one principal question do I have to bind the requested Data to a from or entity to work with it?

Comment: You don't need to bind anything because you use it as a rest API. so you have to use parameter. If you want to bind this with a form, it will be for a view (website for example)

Comment: Ok thank you. But how can I access the values? I tryed loads of possibilities without any result. I even get the above xml returned.